# how to validate time in raddatetimepicker?

Tags: vb.net, telerik, datetimepicker

Thank you for viewing my post. I have a telerik raddatetimepicker integrated within my project. I have a validation control to ensure the end user selects a date. However, how can I validate that the user selects a time? The default time is set to 12:00AM. So, is there a way that I can produce a code that checks to see if there is "12:00 AM" within the textbox? For example, if the textbox does have "12:00 AM" after the date, it throws up an error, and the user can't proceed. The textbox contains both the date and the time together.

I've researched this a lot, and I can't seem to find a way to validate time in the picker.

Thanks again, and I look forward to hearing what you have to say.

NOTE: MY coding is done with VB, and I'm working in Visual Studio 2010.

Josh

```
telerik:raddatetimepicker ID="TimeOfCourse" runat="server" 
                        ShowPopupOnFocus="True" Culture="en-US" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        AutoPostBackControl="TimeView" Height="26px" 
                        HiddenInputTitleAttibute="Visually hidden input created for functionality purposes." 
                        Width="200px" 
                        WrapperTableSummary="Table holding date picker control for selection of dates.">
                        <timeview runat="server" cellspacing="-1" columns="8" interval="00:15:00" />
                        <timepopupbutton hoverimageurl="" imageurl="" />
                        <calendar runat="server" usecolumnheadersasselectors="False" userowheadersasselectors="False" viewselectortext="x" />
                        <dateinput runat="server" dateformat="M/d/yyyy" displaydateformat="M/d/yyyy" 
                            labelwidth="" BorderColor="Red" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                            AutoPostBack="True" Height="26px" />
                        <datepopupbutton hoverimageurl="" imageurl="" />
                    </telerik:raddatetimepicker>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code, otherwise we can't help you very much...

Comment: Sam, thanks for the reply. I added the source code. The only validator I have is a required field validator for the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job (updated)...

```
 Dim userSelectedTime As String = 'The name of your textbox, example: TextBox1.Text
 userSelectedTime = userSelectedTime.Remove(userSelectedTime.LastIndexOf(":"), userSelectedTime.Length - userSelectedTime.LastIndexOf(":"))
 If userSelectedTime = "00:00" Then
    MsgBox("Please enter a different time.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Your app's name")
 End If
```

The only downside to using this code is that it won't accept the time of 00:00, even if the user genuinely enters 00:00.

Comment: Thank you. The time is okay, because the user must select a time, and the time would never be 00:00. However, I get the error stating that 'SelectedTime' is member of the telerik datetimepicker. Is there a way that I could give an error is the textbox has the value of '0:00'? The textbox holds both the date and time.

Comment: Done, the code will now get the text in your textbox, trim off the date so it only has the time in the variable, then compares the time to see if it is 00:00.